# Originate call using adhearsion

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

i have searched google, tried to read adhearsion docs and make sense of the examples.  i understand parts of it but am not able to put it together.  i can edit extensions.conf and do agi(agi://localhost) and handle incoming calls in the dialplan.rb.  i have written an ivr that way which is in use in the real world.

i have edited manager.conf and config/setup.rb and when i do ahn - i see

```
 INFO ami: Successful AMI actions-only connection into ...@127.0.0.1
 INFO ami: Successful AMI events-only connection into ...@127.0.0.1
```

now what i want to know is very specifically the following:

1. where and how do i write code that executes when the adhearsion app starts. i.e. without any event or agi call.
2. what exactly do i write to dial out.

please dont give me partial responses like

```
methods_for :dialplan
  sub foo
    # stuff here
  end
```

please dont give me vague responses like "create component and fork it to the left", or something... i have been reading stuff like that, and i am not able get it.  please tell me specific steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your google foo is quite obviously [sub par](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=adhearsion+originate)

Use the 'after_initialized' event namespace for 1

When do you want to dial out? You need to look at either "dial" in the dialplan, or "originate" elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

extensions.conf

```
[context]

exten => extension_number,1,Noop()

exten => extension_number,n,AGI(agi://localhost)


in adhearsion project directory.

dialplan.rb 

context {
#your code goes here.
dial "SIP/xxxxx"
dial "SIP/xxxxx"
}


for methods:

 your_ahn_directory/components/component_name/lib/component_name.rb


  methods_for :dialplan do

    def sum(n1,n2)

    n1+n2

   end

end
```